# iOS Swift malloc error

Tags: ios, swift, audio, malloc, avaudiofile

I want to record audio on iOS in real time, analyze the raw audio data and save parts of the recorded data. I'm recording the data with this code: https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/ba815fc23b5d642705f2b1dedfaf0107

Now, my data is saved in a Float array and I want to save it to an audio file. I tried doing it with this code:

```
let fileMgr = FileManager.default
    let dirPaths = fileMgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let recordSettings = [AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.min.rawValue,
                      AVEncoderBitRateKey: 16,
                      AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                      AVSampleRateKey: 44100] as [String: Any]
    let soundFileUrl = dirPaths[0].appendingPathComponent("recording-" + getDate() + ".pcm")


    do {
        let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: soundFileUrl, settings: recordSettings)
        let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 2, interleaved: true)

        let audioFileBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: 3000)

        for i in 0..<circBuffer.count {
            audioFileBuffer.int16ChannelData?.pointee[i] = Int16(circBuffer[i])
        }

        try audioFile.write(from: audioFileBuffer)

    }
```

On the last line, I get an error which says:

ERROR:    >avae> AVAudioFile.mm:306: -[AVAudioFile writeFromBuffer:error:]: error -50
amplitudeDemo(79264,0x70000f7cb000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc5b9057e00: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I already searched in a lot of other questions, but I couldn't find anything that helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code at this line:

```
let audioFileBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: 3000)
```

You declare an `AVAudioPCMBuffer` with capacity 3000 frames * 2 channels, which means the allocated buffer for your `audioFileBuffer` can contain 6000 samples. If the index for the channel data exceeds this limit, your code destroys the nearby regions in the heap, which causes **object was probably modified** error.

So, your `circBuffer.count` may probably be exceeding this limit. You need to allocate enough buffer size, for the `AVAudioPCMBuffer`.

```
    do {
        //### You need to specify common format
        let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: soundFileUrl, settings: recordSettings, commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, interleaved: true)

        let channels = 2
        let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 44100, channels: AVAudioChannelCount(channels), interleaved: true)
        let audioFileBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(circBuffer.count / channels)) //<-allocate enough frames
        //### `stride` removed as it seems useless...
        let int16ChannelData = audioFileBuffer.int16ChannelData! //<-cannot be nil for the `format` above

        //When interleaved, channel data of AVAudioPCMBuffer is not as described in its doc:
        //  https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiopcmbuffer/1386212-floatchanneldata .
        //  The following code is modified to work with actual AVAudioPCMBuffer.
        //Assuming `circBuffer` as
        //  Interleaved, 2 channel, Float32
        //  Each sample is normalized to [-1.0, 1.0] (as usual floating point audio format)
        for i in 0..<circBuffer.count {
            int16ChannelData[0][i] = Int16(circBuffer[i] * Float(Int16.max))
        }
        //You need to update `frameLength` of the `AVAudioPCMBuffer`.
        audioFileBuffer.frameLength = AVAudioFrameCount(circBuffer.count / channels)

        try audioFile.write(from: audioFileBuffer)

    } catch {
        print("Error", error)
    }
```

Some notes added as comments, please check them before trying this code.

---

**UPDATE**
Sorry, for showing untested code, two things fixed:

- You need to specify `commonFormat:` when instantiating `AVAudioFile`.
- `int16ChannelData` (and other channel data) does not return expected pointers as described in its documentation when interleaved, data filling loop modified to fit for the actual behaviour.

Please try.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. But still, the generated audio files are empty and I get the error: "ERROR:    >avae> AVAudioFile.mm:306: -[AVAudioFile writeFromBuffer:error:]: error -50" Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @user7310287, sorry, I should have checked my code a little more, I just have checked writing to the buffer does not cause crash. But not checked with the actual write to file would succeed or not. Now checking the actual iOS behaviour, please uncheck the Accept sign till I can find fixes.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have chosen the `frameCapacity` arbitrarily to `3000`.

Set it to the actual sample count:

`let audioFileBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(circBuffer.count))`